# Restoring SQL Server 2000 backup on SQL Server 2012 Developer edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000

There was an effort to restore a SQL Server 2000 backup file on to a SQL Server 2012 Developer version database.

It fails and shows the version is not compatible?Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you make **sure** that the target is really SQL Server 2012? `SELECT @@VERSION` will tell you what **engine version** you're running against - maybe it's only the 2012 Management Studio? The restore from 2008 R2 to 2012 should be no issue at all

Comment: thanks for the sugestion.There is a mistake from my side.The source database is sql 2000 and not sql 2008r2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 does **NOT** have a direct upgrade for SQL Server 2000 anymore - source is just plain **too old**

You'll need to take your SQL Server 2000 backup and restore it to a 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 server, then take a backup from there, and restore that new backup on SQL Server 2012.

See e.g. [Migration SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/06/15/migration-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2012.aspx) or many other blog posts and articles in the inner webs that describe this in great detail.

Comment: Thanks so,can I install a new sql server 2008 on the m/c ,where there is a 2012 developer edition exist?